# R: How to create clusters based on row strings

Tags: r, nlp, n-gram, lemmatization

I m trying to create clusters from data based on the string value of each row. I m using the R langage. What I m calling a "cluster" is a big thematic (= family) that can define each keywords. I imagine something autogenearated based on the keyword, maybe by using lemmatization or ngram.

For example both keywords "cloud services" and "the cloud service" should be in the "service" cluster.

Here is my input vector:

```
keywords_df <- c("cloud storage", "cloud computing", "google cloud storage", "the cloud service", 
        "free cloud storage", "what is cloud computing", "best cloud storage","cloud computing definition", 
        "amazon cloud services", "cloud service providers", "cloud services", "google cloud computing", "cloud computing services", "benefits of cloud computing")
```

Here is the expected output dataframe:

```
| Keyword                   |  Thematic |
|---------------------------|:---------:|
|cloud storage              |storage  |
|cloud computing            |computing|
|google cloud storage       |storage  |
|the cloud service          |service  |
|free cloud storage         |storage  |
|what is cloud computing    |computing|
|best cloud storage         |storage  |
|cloud computing definition |computing|
|amazon cloud service       |service |
|cloud service providers        |services |
|cloud service              |service |
|google cloud computing     |computing|
|cloud computing services   |service |
|benefits of cloud computing|computing|
```

The goal is to clean up the data in the "keyword" column and auto extract a kind of lemm or ngram.

Here is what I have done for now :

1. Create the "Thematic" column based on keyword column:

   ```
   keywords_df <- mutate(keywords_df,Thematic=Keyword)
   keywords_df$Thematic <- as.character(keywords_df$Thematic)
   ```
2. Remove Stopwords:

   ```
   stopwords_list<-(c("cloud")) #Remove the main word
   stopwords <- stopwords(kind = "en")
   stopwords <- append(stopwords,stopwords_list)
   x  = keywords_df$Thematic        
   x  =  removeWords(x,stopwords)
   keywords_df$Thematic <- x
   ```

Comment: Do you have a list of "thematic families" to group the `Keyword`, or should one assume the families purely from the `Keyword` vector (supervised or unsupervised)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have no list of "thematic families". The family should be create from the 'Keyword' vector, based on lemmatization, ngram or another NLP technic. NB 1: A keyword could generate several thematics (separated by comma)
NB 2: The script should consider plurals, gender, etc as a single thematic (ex: « Small usb key », « what are the smallest usb keys » and «  the smallest usb key » should give the « small » thematic.)

Comment: @Remi I edited my old answer to include your updated/clarified question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the presence of certain words like `storage`, `computing` and `service` by using `grepl()`. This way, you can check for the presence of a given word in `df`:

```
fams   <- c("storage", "computing", "service")
family <- rep("emtpy_fam", length(df))

for(fam in fams){
  family[grepl(fam, Keywords)] <- fam
}
cbind(df, family)
#      Keywords                      family     
# [1,] "cloud storage"               "storage"  
# [2,] "cloud computing"             "computing"
---
#[13,] "cloud computing services"    "service"  
#[14,] "benefits of cloud computing" "computing"
```

There are certainly nicer ways of doing this, though

---

**Edit:** Nicer way to do it, using the `stringr` package

```
library(stringr)
family <- str_extract(df, pattern="storage|computing|service")
cbind(df, family)
```

---

**Edit2:** I see your latest edit, indicating that you are looking for non pre-specified family descriptions. The first method I think of in such a case is [Latent Dirichlet Allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) (LDA - not to be confused with Linear Discriminant Analysis, though).

LDA analyzes a corpus of documents and identifies latent topics as a distribution of words (found like `terms(lda.output)` below) and identifies which document belongs to which topic (found like `topic(lda.output)` below):

```
library(topicmodels)
library(tm)

# Preliminary textmining
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(df))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, "cloud")
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)

# Term Frequency matrix
TF <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus, control = list(weighting = weightTf))

lda.output <- LDA(TF, k=3)
terms(lda.output)
# Topic 1  Topic 2  Topic 3 
# "servic" "comput" "storag"

cbind(df, terms(lda.output)[topics(lda.output)])
#            df                                    
#Topic 3 "cloud storage"               "storag"
#Topic 2 "cloud computing"             "comput"
#Topic 3 "google cloud storage"        "storag"
#Topic 1 "cloud services"              "servic"
#Topic 3 "free cloud storage"          "storag"
#Topic 2 "what is cloud computing"     "comput"
#Topic 3 "best cloud storage"          "storag"
#Topic 1 "cloud computing definition"  "servic"
#Topic 1 "amazon cloud services"       "servic"
#Topic 3 "cloud service providers"     "storag"
#Topic 2 "google cloud services"       "comput"
#Topic 2 "google cloud computing"      "comput"
#Topic 1 "cloud computing services"    "servic"
#Topic 2 "benefits of cloud computing" "comput"
```

Final note: If you wish to get `"computing"` instead of `"comput"` etc., you should change the stemming part in the text-mining. You can also leave this out, but then `"service"` and `"services"` will not be recognised as the same word. You could, however, manually replace `"service"` with `"services"` or vice versa.

Comment: This does not seem like what the OP is looking for. I imagine OP wanted some kind of unsupervised clustering method while assigning each cluster with the most frequent word per cluster. `fams` should not be given, but derived from `Keyword` itself.

Comment: Wow, I see the edit now. I was in a whole other ball park

Comment: @useR I added an unsupervised 'clustering'  method to my answer, in case you are interested

Comment: I remember learning this in graduate school. Thanks for the refresher!

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!